# Changing the permlink and SEO

Tags: permalinks

I have a doubt on changing my permlink structure for the second time. What happened was I have moved my old website to the wordpress blog by copying all the posts.

After the migration, i have set the 301 redirect to the new url of wordpress and now it is updated in the google. After that I found the permlink is not good I am changing the structure to shorter url.

I found the old urls are correctly redirected to the new one i think it is handled by the wordpress. Will it be a 301 redirect by the wordpress?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the status of the redirect using any number of developer tools (chrome can do this by default).  I believe the default redirect that wordpress does when the post title is changed is a 301, but I could be mistaken.  If you need finer control (or would like regex support), the [Redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) is a great option, and it supports 301, 302, 307, and 404 codes out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If the last part of your permalink structure always was the post name or the post ID WordPress will handle the redirect just fine. There are some [edge cases](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15665) but these should not affect you if you haven't noticed them before.